# Azure RM Templates nested templates leftovers

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

After deploying this template https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/active-directory-new-domain-ha-2-dc I have some nested templates resources in my Resource Group.

[image]

How can I modify the original template so that nested templates work as intended, but don't appear in the Resource Group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those are not nested template leftovers, those are VM extensions that you've installed on your vm's to do things (create domain, in this case).

Recently Microsoft introduced a debatable change, where several types of resource that were previously invisible in the portal (in resource group view) became visible.

As far as I know, there it no way to make them go away, besides deleting the VM extensions, which can probably be done in your case, as the Domain was already established.